# Graphs adjacency vectors - files

Tags: c, random, graph

I need some graphs represented as adjacency vectors. The number of vertexes can achieve some tens of thousands (e.g. 20.000-50.000). Don't know if it matters, I am using **C** code.

Do you know any site where I can retrieve such data files?

Answer (score 0):

A very praxis relevant graph is a digital road map. (As used in navigation systems)
`OpenStreetMap` provides these vectors. But you have to build up yourself the adjacencies.

Comment: I appreciate the info, but I am looking for the complete graphs.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to find some resources:

 1. http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/mgd/gdb.html
 2. http://snap.stanford.edu/data/
 3. http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Datasets
 4. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/metis_graph/metis_graph.html
 5. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/data.html
 6. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/cities/cities.html
 7. http://staffweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~wc06/partition/#0

A.M.